# Query doesn't insert medium/large text

Tags: php

I have this pretty awkward problem that my query won't insert medium/large texts. When i try for example to insert/update my database records with `Tester` it works, but when i try to insert/update four lines of text, it doesn't do anything (won't give me an error either). The really strange part is that it does process two 'lorem ipsum' paragraphs.

My query just looks like this (for the insert):

```
$ncp_id = $defaults->query("INSERT INTO ".$table[0]." (p_id, p_title, p_date, p_desc) VALUES ('','".$_POST['p_title']."','".$_POST['p_date']."','".$_POST['p_desc']."')");
$defaults->query("INSERT INTO ".$table[2]." (ncp_id, ncp_client_id, ncp_project_id) VALUES ('','".$_POST['c_name']."','".$ncp_id."')");
```

My database field is a `TEXT` type.

All the post data are legit. When i print these, i see the texts that *should* be inserted

I don't have any more information, or code. I'm really hoping someone heard of a simular problem before.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I think the problem is in the structure of table design. Check the p_desc field for it is text type ? It may be varchar or something else.

Comment: I know it's vulnerable, thnx, but it will be used by one person for his own website. I trust the man ;). Oh, and the type is TEXT (no varchar)

Comment: my bet: your description text has single quotes in it. This will break your querystring. Lorem ipsum won't break it because it has no apostrophes.

Comment: also, no errors: it's because you're using PDO without setting PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION thus it's failing silently

Comment: @Maurice That's like saying you're building a car with no brakes because you trust the driver to drive slowly enough to roll to a stop. Deliberately leaving massive security vulnerabilities in code is **never** acceptable.

Comment: It was about the single quote's in te text. This proves @Mansfield comment right. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that real mediumtext contains special characters that breaks a query.

#### That's why you have to use prepared statements

instead of interpolating data right in the query string.

Also, we know nothing of the `query()` implementation and if it can return a scalar value like this.

Also, you have to configure your DBAL and PHP to translate database errors into PHP errors and to make the latter available to you. That's most important part. Without an error message you can guess for ages, while with it you will know the problem on sight.